# How to set a static IP to my container for a pre-existent external network in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml (to create a VPN + docker network just accessible by VPN clients):

```
version: "3" 
services:   wireguard:
    image: linuxserver/wireguard
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/Santiago
      - SERVERURL=auto #optional
      - SERVERPORT=51820 #optional
      - PEERS=5 #optional
      - PEERDNS=auto #optional
      - INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.13.13.0 #optional
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - ./lib/modules:/lib/modules
    ports:
      - 51820:51820/udp
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped
```

This above compose create a network named **wireguard_default**:

```
"Name": "wireguard_default",
        "Id": "ecc19ea95073e2c1ba785fe240c29027f39d1b47977b0f1bdff5c064d6188e81",
        "Created": "2020-08-15T20:59:36.238911179Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.23.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
```

So, I had created a **webserver** with the following compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
    networks:
      default:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: wireguard_default
```

The compose set a IP automatically, which allow access to the web from my browser (http://172.23.0.3) just when I am connected to the VPN.

```
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.23.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
```

Everything is working fine up to here. But I need to set a STATIC IP (example: 172.23.0.25) in my webserver compose for the nginx container.

How can I do for set in the compose a static IP that allow it connect to the external network created by VPN Compose?

Comment: Hi, interesting, is the output of `ipaddr` helpful

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Hmm I'm not quite sure. perhaps this might be of interest https://forums.docker.com/t/static-ipv4-for-container-in-pre-existing-external-network/64634

Comment: i get this error: "ERROR: for web  user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets"

Comment: i just post a solution @IronMan. Thanks for your information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!

I get it.

I just edit the VPN compose to add the subnet in the "networks" options:

```
version: "3" 
services:   wireguard:
    image: linuxserver/wireguard
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/Santiago
      - SERVERURL=auto #optional
      - SERVERPORT=51820 #optional
      - PEERS=5 #optional
      - PEERDNS=auto #optional
      - INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.13.13.0 #optional
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - ./lib/modules:/lib/modules
    ports:
      - 51820:51820/udp
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.23.0.0/24
```

and add the static IP in the compose networks options of each docker to connect after.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.23.0.25


networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: wireguard_default
```